# NaN as output from kernlab's Gaussian process prediction

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a regression problem using *gausspr* function in *kernlab*. The input is standardized. but the output of predict(model, test.set) turns out to be a set of NaN values!

training set, X

```
M1 -0.3437191 -0.1755636 -0.1914969 -0.205308 -0.1595554
M2 -0.3437191 -0.1755636 -0.1914969 -0.205308 -0.1595554
M3 -0.3437191 -0.1755636 -0.1914969 -0.205308 -0.1595554
M4 -0.3437191 -0.1755636 -0.1914969 -0.205308 -0.1595554
M5 -0.3437191 -0.1755636 -0.1914969 -0.205308 -0.1595554
```

training output, Y is

```
Y = c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

test set, Z

```
T1   1.5530507 -0.2152377 -0.202634 -0.1460405 -0.1592964
T2   1.5530507 -0.2152377 -0.202634 -0.1460405 -0.1592964
T3 -0.3736244 -0.2152377 -0.202634 -0.1460405 -0.1592964
T4 -0.3736244 -0.2152377 -0.202634 -0.1460405 -0.1592964
T5 -0.3736244 -0.2152377 -0.202634 -0.1460405 -0.1592964
```

the code:

```
library(kernlab)
model <- gausspr(X,Y)
predict(model, Z)
```

Output is

```
> head(res14)
     [,1]
[1,]  NaN
[2,]  NaN
[3,]  NaN
[4,]  NaN
[5,]  NaN
[6,]  NaN
```

I am wondering why I am getting this output.

Comment: I just noticed I had zero variance in my dataset ! that could a reason for such a behavioral !

Comment: Please make your example reproducible...

Comment: what does `[1,2,3,4,5]` stands for here? and what is `res14`?

Comment: it is just an arbitrary reposnce variable. 1, is the output of M1, 2 output of M2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So because, the input data has a set of zero variance columns, making the covarance matrix would be possible (can some one say why ?) and the final result would be NaN values.

Comment: Covariance matrix does not need to be positive definite (it has to be positive semi-definite however, but just not full rank), it's when you need to invert the covariance matrix (to get the precision matrix) that you are in trouble.